# returning references in c++ functions

Tags: c++, reference

even though I think I uderstand references, I don't know whether there's a difference between these 2 (both work):

```c++
(includes and that stuff)

//doesn't return a reference to a vector
vector<int> ref_to_vec1(vector<int>& vec) {
  vec.push_back(whatever);
  return vec;
}

//returns a REFERENCE to a vector
vector<int>& ref_to_vec2(vector<int>& vec) {
  vec.push_back(whatever);
  return vec;
}

vector<int> v;

//Both append whatever to v
ref_to_vec1(v);
ref_to_vec2(v);
```

What is the point of returning a reference with functions?

And in this case, what is the point of returning anything at all? You just need to call the function with the vector, without assigning anything to the result of the function.

Thank you!

Comment: You use references when you don't want to make copies.

Comment: Lets you modify the data so that my_vector[1138]=92 actually sets the value inside the vector, as opposed to setting the value in a copy - which wouldn't do anything.

Comment: In this case you aren't returning nothing. 
You are calling the functions like they return void.
Both functions do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And in this case, what is the point of returning anything at all? You
>   just need to call the function with the vector, without assigning
>   anything to the result of the function.

Nothing. Maybe a `bool` to indicate failure or success (It's what the WinAPI does) but other than that if you use a reference in the parameter list that is to be filled instead of using the return value of a function then you don't need to return anything at all.

---

The point of returning references is to avoid copying over the object that you want to return. `ref_to_vec1()` copies* the `vec` you pass to it when it returns and you save the return value:

```
auto v2 = ref_to_vec1(v); // v2 is a copy of v, changing v2 doesn't change v
auto& v3 = ref_to_vec2(v); // v3 is a reference to v, any changes made to v3 are made to v too.
```

---

*Unless it's optimized out by (N)RVO or moved (C++11 or higher).

Comment: Thank you, I just thought that it didn't make much sense to return anything, but since I'm a beginner and the code I had seen did I thought I'd ask!

Answer (score 2):

Case 1  obvious  as explained by Mikhail

Case 2  your function create a new object and return a reference to it, or give access to something already instanciated; like a singleton

Case 3 : you want to chain operators, typically happening for streaming operator;  myStream << firstVal << secondVal;

I am pretty sure this question is a duplicate and must already have excellent answers on this site

Comment: You're right on all points but you mentioned singletons like that's something we actually want to deal with in our lives. I want to downvote you because of the singleton, but I can't, because you're right.

Comment: @Clearer :  oh yes...  unfortunately in real world production old legacy code you may find some MySuperSingleton & getInstance()  crappy code :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use reference, there is the second vector object, which returns from the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think, a part of confusion is the fact that there are conceptually two groups of functions - the ones which process the argument in some way and return a result of it, and the ones which act on the argument. Some languages even have this distinction built into the language - for example, in Pascal you have 'procedure' and 'function'. Former can't return anything, while the latter has to.

What you have in your case, is a procedural thing - it acts on the argument, in your case, adds an element. It doesn't generally need to return anything (`vector::push_back()` never fails).